# Org Agenda Shows error

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Debugger Shows this error when trying to set agenda

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-activate-links)
  org-activate-links(192)
  org-agenda-finalize()
  org-agenda-list(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda-list nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-list)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)`


  [image]

Comment: Please add the full output of `M-x org-version` to your question.

Comment: org version **8.2.10**

Comment: Do i have to manually update org to v9. Emacs 25 will not do it for me.